# Get PromiseState When Using Fetch

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api

I have the following function that uses fetch:

```
function requests(url) {
  return fetch(url)
    .catch(function (error) {
      return null;
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      if (response == null) {
        return null;
      } else if (!response.ok) {
        if (response.status == 422) {
          // HIT No longer exists
          return null;
        } else if (response == 429) {
          //too many requests
          return null;
        }
        console.log("caught error: " + response.status);
        return null;
      }
      js = response.json();
      console.log(js);
      return js;
    });
}
```

My problem is that occasionally the fetch is 'rejected'. None of the code catches that error until I try to read 'response.json'. I cannot find how to access the 'PromiseState' in 'js'. When I log "js" I get this:

```
Promise
  [[Prototype]]: Promise
  [[PromiseState]]: "rejected"
  [[PromiseResult]]: SyntaxError:      Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Try to use async/await ```await response.json()```

Comment: Try to use async/await, what should be your expected result - it should be either HTML or JSON? If json, use this ```await response.json()``` or else use this for HTML```await response.text()```

Comment: The result should be json. I tried adding async/await but I get an error saying await is only valid in async functions. I edited my OP to show what I did.

Comment: You have add async inside .then like this ```.then(async function() { ... })```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it, sort of. I'm getting the same error but in the calling function. I need to investigate that.

Comment: You handle the JSON parsing error by doing `response.json().catch(err => { console.error(err); return null; })` just like you did with the `fetch()` promise itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `await js = response.json();` your code assigns a *promise* to `js`, while it would be more useful to do `js = await response.json();` to get the promised value.

Moreover, `js` is apparently declared with an implicit global scope. It would be good to use `let`, `const` or `var` to make it local.

While for the first promise (`fetch`) your code has error handling, there is none for this second promise `.json()`.

Finally, `response == 429` is never going to be true. I suppose you intended to test the `status` property.

Here is how it would look without `.then`/`.catch`, but with a `try/catch` block:

```
async function requests(url) {µ
    try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        if (!response?.ok) {
            if (response && ![422, 429].includes(response.status)) {
                console.log("caught error: " + response.status);
            }
            return null;
        }
        const js = await response.json();
        console.log(js);
        return js;
    } catch(error) {
        return null;
    }
}
```